# SQL server 2008 R2, select one value of a column for each distinct value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

On SQL  server 2008 R2, I would like to select one value of a column for each distinct value of another column.

e.g.

```
 name   id_num
 Tom      53
 Tom      60
 Tom      27
 Jane     16
 Jane     16
 Bill     97
 Bill     83
```

I need to get one id_num for each distinct name, such as

```
 name   id_num
 Tom      27
 Jane     16
 Bill     97
```

For each name, the id_num can be randomly picked up (not required to be max or min) as long as it is associated with the name.

For example, for Bill,  I can pick up 97 or 83. Either one is ok.

I do know how to write the SQL query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 name,MIN(id_num)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY name
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want pick id_num randomly, you may try this

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    name, id_num,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY newid())
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40817/5)

Comment: thanks, what if I want to pick up the id_num randomly not only the min one ?

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the max id like this:

```
SELECT name, MAX(id_num)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name
```

That would get you one id for each distinct name.

Comment: thanks, what if I want to pick up the id_num randomly not only the max one ?

Comment: I was trying to come up with something, but it looks like EricZ beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

select name, max(id_num)
from [mytable]
group by name

Comment: thanks, what if I want to pick up the id_num randomly not only the max one ?

Comment: If it's random then surely you don't care if it's min or max, thus min or max are acceptable, simple solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The (SELECT 1) in the cte does not really order the data in each of the partitions. which should give you the random selection.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    name VARCHAR(10)
    , id_num INT
)
INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT 'Tom', 53 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tom', 60 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tom', 27 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane', 16 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jane', 16 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bill', 97 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bill', 83

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID
        , name
        , id_num
    FROM #tmp
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: . . Ordering by a constant does *not* give you a random value.  It produces an arbitrary value, but there is no reason to believe that the choice is random (for instance, some values might never get chosen).