# SQL 2008 R2 CTE syntax error in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question is based on my previous question

[SQL server 2008 R2, select one value of a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454241/sql-server-2008-r2-select-one-value-of-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of-anot)

about CTE on SQL server 2008.

```
   WITH my_cte(id_num, rn) AS (
      SELECT name, 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.name ORDER BY newid())
            FROM my_table as a
      )
   SELECT id_num FROM my_cte WHERE rn = 1

   INSERT INTO #temp_table 
   SELECT a.address from another_table as a,
            id_num from my_cte  -- here, I got error!!!
```

Why I got error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

I need to get a new table with one column from another_table and one column from my_cte.

e.g.

```
 address (from another_table)    id_num (from my_cte)
  city_1                        65 
  city_1                        36
  city_2                        65
  city_2                        36
  city_3                        65
  city_3                        36
```

**What kinds of join I should use to get the above table so that each address is associated with all id_num from the CTE ?** Suppose that id_num has only 65 and 36 two values.  my_cte has no column of address.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is this trying to do exactly?  `SELECT * FROM 
   (
  SELECT a.address from another_table as a,
            id_num from my_cte  -- **I got error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.**
    ) as t`

Comment: Yeah I see it.. this `SELECT a.address from another_table as a, id_num from my_cte` is invalid... I'm asking what you are intending to do here.

Comment: Did you already create your temp table, or are you trying to Select Into?

Answer (score 2):

A CTE can only be used in the statement directly after it.  After you do `SELECT id_num FROM my_cte WHERE rn = 1`, the cte no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

The CTE only exists for a single query.  But you can use it with `insert` as well as `select`:

```
   WITH my_cte(id_num, rn) AS (
      SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.name ORDER BY newid()) as rn
      FROM my_table as a
   )
   INSERT INTO #temp_table 
       SELECT a.address, id_num
       from another_table as a JOIN
            my_cte
            on a.name = my_cte.name;
```

Comment: The select in the `INSERT` is still not valid.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I got the same error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from' my_cte.

Comment: this is because there are two FROM clauses

Comment: There are two `FROM` clauses in your last `SELECT`.

Comment: I need to insert two columns from two different tables, how to do that  ? thanks

Comment: @user3448011 . . . You need to join the tables together.

Comment: Would you please tell me which join I should use to get the table with columns of address (from another_table), id_num (from my_cte) ?