# SQL server 2008, get a new table by selecting two columns from two different tables that do not share same column information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

this question is based on

[SQL 2008 R2 CTE syntax error in a SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455876/sql-2008-r2-cte-syntax-error-in-a-select-statement)

On SQL server 2008, I need to get a new table by selecting two columns from two different tables.

```
  address (from another_table)    id_num (from a cte created by me)
  city_1                        65 
  city_1                        36
  city_2                        65
  city_2                        36
  city_3                        65
  city_3                        36
```

Suppose that id_num has only 65 and 36 two values. The cte has no column of "address". the another_table has no column of id_num.

for each address, I need to associate all id_num in cte to the address

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how will you link the addresses to the id_num?

Comment: @Martin K., for each address, I need to associate all id_num in cte to the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't a join, and you want to associate all id_nums to all addresses, then use:

```
select distinct address, id_num
from another_table, cte
```

If you want the id_num to only be associated with addresses that match some criteria add a where clause:

```
where cte.field1 = address.field1
```

Comment: You should add DISTINCT to get the desired result

Comment: @MartinK. True.  I didn't notice the duplicate addresses.  Thanks.